# sizeof is used to calculate the size of any datatype, measured in the number of bytes. Doesn't it mean that number of bytes is an integer?

Tags: c++, c, sizeof

When I run these two programs which uses sizeof() operator produces the following output. The only difference between 2 codes is that d is initialized to 0 in first code and -1 in second one. Why second program is not entering in the loop body?

**1)**

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
int d;
printf("Before loop\n");
 for(d=0;d<=sizeof(int);d++)
 {  
  printf("sizeof operator\n");
 }
 printf("After loop\n");
return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
Before loop
sizeof operator
sizeof operator
sizeof operator
sizeof operator
sizeof operator
After loop
```

**2)**

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
int d;
printf("Before loop\n");
 for(d=-1;d<=sizeof(int);d++)
 {  
  printf("sizeof operator\n");
 }
   printf("After loop\n");
  return 0;
 }
```

**Output:**

```
Before loop
After loop
```

Comment: `sizeof` returns the size as `size_t`, which is unsigned.

Comment: signed and unsigned comparison in second code snippet. It will compare -1 i.e **0xffffFFFF** which is greater then **0x00000100** that is the reason it never enters the loop

Comment: Your compiler should've notified you with a warning. Never turn off or ignore warnings.